# I sourced my .bashrc file and now get: “-bash: /usr/bin/whoami: Argument list too long” so that I can't execute any commands. Using ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, environment-variables, path

I use an external HPC system via ssh. Today I tried to install "ASE" a Python code for dealing with atoms. I followed instructions to modify my `.bashrc` file but kept getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ase'` So I executed a `source` command for my `.bashrc` file, thinking that would be necessary to get the changes to the `.bashrc` file recognized (unfortunately, I don't remember the exact command).

Now when I try to execute any kind of command (even after logging out and logging back in), I get:

```
###################################################################################### (<-- normal welcome message that I always get on login up to here)
-bash: /usr/bin/whoami: Argument list too long
-bash: /usr/bin/cut: Argument list too long
-bash: /usr/bin/logger: Argument list too long
me@n01:~>
```

I have looked around online for a solution, but don't see any examples of this particular situation. Most people who get the same error still seem to be able to access their files. Can anyone help?

I can't login as root because this is a system I'm accessing via ssh.  I can't access my `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files without getting the error.

Comment: Log in but start another shell? `ssh -t user@host /bin/sh`

Comment: I tried that.  I can login but if I try to do anything else, I get the error.

Comment: So you get a prompt?  It would be helpful if you could show the text of an SSH session in the question (including the error message).

Comment: I get a ">" symbol.

Comment: And if you run commands there, you get the same error?

Comment: Correct, @ Panki.  Let me clarify.  When I open a new terminal and ssh/login, I immediately get this:

-bash: /usr/bin/whoami: Argument list too long
-bash: /usr/bin/cut: Argument list too long
-bash: /usr/bin/logger: Argument list too long

Then the prompt is this:
me@system:~>

Comment: I modified the question to show exactly what I see when I login.  I will now double-check that Kusalananda's suggestion doesn't work...

Comment: You errors are arising from `update-motd` or something, which is printing what you call the "welcome message" - otherwise this should *not* appear when directly starting `sh`

Comment: @Kusalananda, I double-checked your suggestion (logged in with ssh -t).  I still get the error immediately on login though and can't open the .bashrc without getting the error.

Comment: @Panki, thank you for that explanation.  Do you know how I can get past the error to get to the .bashrc file?

Comment: The important bit (`/bin/sh`) is at the end of `ssh -t`. Please confirm that you included this.

Comment: @Panki, sorry I didn't include that.  I thought it must be something specific to Kusalananda's situation.  I included it just now.  I logged in and now see only "sh-4.4$ " (no "welcome").  Thank you for that.  What should I do now?  I see that I can open my .bashrc!  Thank you!

Comment: @Kusalananda, your solution worked (thanks a lot).  Do you want to put it in an answer so I can mark it as correct?  I was able to login and modify the .bashrc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your text correctly, then you are quite possibly sourcing the `~/.bashrc` recursively, either from itself, or it and `~/.bash_profile` are sourcing each other indefinitely (it's not clear from the question). The effect of this would likely be that one or several environment variables are growing out of proportion, which would lead to the error message that you quote.

To fix this, you will have to access your account without starting the `bash` shell.

You can do that with, for example,

```
ssh -t user@host /bin/sh
```

(where `user@host` is your username on and the host's address).  This starts the `/bin/sh` shell rather than your default login shell.  The `/bin/sh` shell does not normally source the `~/.bashrc` file, so you would not have the same issue with this shell. You could pick any other shell, but the `/bin/sh` shell is more or less guaranteed to exist.

This would allow you to log into the account, into a possibly unfamiliar but fully functional shell, to fix the issue, which, again, seems to be related to recursively sourcing the `~/.bashrc` file in one way or another.

I have not addressed the issue you had with Python. That issue may be something that you may want to ask a separate question about, after making sure that your local sysadmin team can't help you with it first.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You are recursively adding the contents of `.bashrc` to `.bashrc`

One way out of that is to set your `PATH` variable to a sane value, then executing external programs should work (you will have to modify .bashrc though so that it doesn't happen again).

```
$ PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

and then, for example:

```
$ vi .bashrc
```

Comment: thank you for explaining.  I can't access .bashrc right now though because I get the error no matter what I do.

Comment: Are you sure that you cannot type `PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` and then Enter at the prompt?

Comment: yes, unfortunately, I couldn't type anything without getting the error.  Just now I tried Kusalananda's suggestion about logging in and it worked though.  So now I'm in and can access the .bashrc.  I'm trying to figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: The reason nothing seems to be working could (possibly) be due to the shell failing to execute commands in `$PROMPT_COMMAND`. Safer to just start another shell and sort it out from there...